# How to apply screen orientation to portrait too all the layouts at once android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, screen-orientation, portrait

Hello im making an app where i want is that all the layouts should be lock in potrait inshrot i want my app in potrait even user try to make it in landscape

i have some idea but dont if it works or not

in my app i have only one main activity and all rest of are fragments so my idea is if i give reqiredActivity to potrait to main activity will it work

right now im giving each fragment requiredAcitivity to potrait but when i have many fragments in the future it can be a hastle for me

```
 requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it in your activity Manifest XML. `screenOrientation`.

```
<activity
            android:name=".Android_mobile_infoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Comment: Look at the example

Answer (score 2):

In the Activity Manifest file for all activity

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or create a BaseActivity and add

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Then extend it in all activities.

Or Create an application class

```
class MyApp: Application(), Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
    }
}
```

Then add .MyApp under application tag

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        .. 
        />
```